# I want to upload image from apachecommons file upload using jsp servlet but it will show java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

here is the error shown by eclipse
![this eclipse folder structure][1]

```
Nov 13, 2013 6:46:38 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Image] in context with path [/uploadimg] threw exception
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
    at java.lang.String.substring(Unknown Source)
    at com.vaibhav.upload.doPost(upload.java:72)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

..........................................................................................

UPLOAD.java(servlet code)

```
package com.vaibhav;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItem;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItemFactory;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload;
import org.imgscalr.Scalr;

public class upload extends HttpServlet {
    private boolean isMultipart;
    String ofileName;
    String fieldName;
    String contentType;
    File usersDir = null;

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        isMultipart = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request);
        System.out.println("hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh");
        if (!isMultipart) {
        } else {

            File fobj = new File(getServletContext().getRealPath("\\"));
            FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory(1024 * 5, fobj);
            ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
            List items = null;
            System.out.println("hiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii");
            try {
                items = upload.parseRequest(request);
            } catch (FileUploadException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println(items);
            Iterator itr1 = items.iterator();
            FileItem fileItem = null;

            while (itr1.hasNext()) {
                FileItem item = (FileItem) itr1.next();
                if (item.isFormField()) {
                    item.getFieldName();
                    item.getString();
                } else {
                    fileItem = item;
                    String finalName;
                    fieldName = item.getFieldName();
                    ofileName = item.getName();
                    contentType = fileItem.getContentType();
                    finalName = ofileName
                            .substring(ofileName.lastIndexOf("\\"));
                    finalName = ofileName;
                    usersDir = new File(getServletContext().getRealPath("\\")
                            + "\\users\\" + "\\images\\" + finalName);
                    try {
                        fileItem.write(usersDir);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    String imgExt = usersDir.getAbsolutePath().substring(
                            usersDir.getAbsolutePath().lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
                    BufferedImage bimg = new BufferedImage(100, 100,
                            BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
                    bimg.createGraphics().drawImage(
                            ImageIO.read(usersDir).getScaledInstance(170, 150,
                                    java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH), 0, 0, null);
                    BufferedImage bimg2 = Scalr.resize(bimg, 150);
                    ImageIO.write(bimg2, imgExt, new File(getServletContext()
                            .getRealPath("\\")
                            + "\\users\\"
                            + "\\images\\thumb_" + finalName));
                }
                RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext()
                        .getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/webpages/home.jsp");
                dispatcher.forward(request, response);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

...........................................................................................
index.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>file upload</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="file" size="50"><br/> <input
            type="submit" value="uploadfile">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

![the error that show on console][10]

i want that it will create run time folder and subfolder for each user .....

Comment: `lastIndexOf` will return -1 if it doesn't find the target in the searched string.  It is *never* safe to use `substring` directly on the return from `lastIndexOf`

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is on this line:

```
finalName = ofileName.substring(ofileName.lastIndexOf("\\"));
```

This is on line 72 of your source file for Upload.java, which you can readily get from the stack trace.

`ofileName` doesn't contain any `\` characters, so `lastIndexOf` is returning `-1` which `substring` can't use as a beginning index.  Attempting to do this will give you exactly the exception that you're getting.

Instead, do this.

```
int nameStart = ofileName.lastIndexOf("\\");
if (nameStart > -1) {
    finalName = ofileName.substring(nameStart);
} else {
    finalName = ofileName;  // there's nothing to substring
}
```

Comment: thanxs lan.......i have done this it will give filenotfound Exception at line no. 80 and imageio Exception at line no. 80...i get the tmp image on .plugin folder of my project  but it will not render to next page(home.java) basically i want to create a users folder than subfolder name image than in the image folder all the image which are uploaded will store with its thumbnail......help me out from this situation...

Comment: if you want to create a folder, then you'll need to call the `File.mkdir` or `File.mkdirs` method.  However, your original question has been addressed, so it's probably time for you to start a new question.